# JSP output getting trucated in tomcat 8.0.17

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat

I was trying to migrate to tomcat 8.0.17 from 8.0.15. After migration I noticed some strange behavior that output html of JSP is getting truncated after some size.

There is no fixed file size of html, for some pages 10 KB output was coming, for some 7 KB and for some 18 KB output, as seen in firebug. But for all pages there is some html that got truncated at the bottom.

Is it because of some subtle change occurred in 8.0.17 or my code is lacking some configuration?

My tag file header is as follows

```
<%@tag description="Root layout file for generating all the pages" pageEncoding="UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
```

And my JSP file headers is as follows

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
```

I tried using `buffer="none"` in JSP header, but of no use.

Exact same code is working in tomcat 8.0.15. Does anyone else noticed such thing?

Comment: adding this help you `<%@page buffer="500kb" autoFlush="true" %>`, tune the value 500kb

Comment: Does it truncate every JSP? You can try to find the cause by "bisection method" - i.e. delete (or JSP comment out) half of the content, try it, then delete or comment out the second half, ... Also if you have compression enabled, I would turn it off.

Comment: And other thing - how much data do get truncated? Are we talking about bytes or tens of bytes. Seems more like a problem of some servlet filter or wrapper to me.

Comment: Also I can see that 8.0.16 made some changes in ACK sending with NIO (http://ci.apache.org/projects/tomcat/tomcat8/docs/changelog.html). So a quick question - are you using NIO connectors? Are you using HTTP, HTTPS or are you behind AJP proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem so did others. 
The bug has been reported on Tomcat and it is going to be fix in the next release.
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57476

I tried the recommended temporary fixes: changing connector, <%page buffer, and the output param for the default servlet but none worked for me.